# How to differentiate events added via Outlook side panel

Tags: activities, user-management, salesforce-for-outlook

With Activities created via Chatter publisher, I have a Boolean tagging them as coming via the publisher. This was originally used to prevent double chatter posting, but now it helps us understand user interaction.
Is it possible to do something to Activities created via the Outlook side panel?

There are no layout/field options on that publisher. Thanks!

Comment: My initial solution is to check a Boolean when a record is saved with no WhatId nor WhoId, and prevent this from the GUI via page layouts.

Comment: Is this outlook desktop or.outlook web access.  I once had custom publisher for outlook desktop and was able to customize the fields.  It just has to be a global action.

Comment: I could add a custom field to the Outlook side panel, but this wouldn't affect an Event added via the Outlook calendar.